# Mean over a certain time-period in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have hourly data of CO2 values and I would like to know what is the CO2 concentration during the night (e.g. 9pm-7am). A reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate)

times <- seq(ymd_hms("2020-01-01 08:00:00"),
ymd_hms("2020-01-04 08:00:00"),  by = "1 hours")
values <- runif(length(times), 1, 15)
df <- tibble(times, values)
```

How to get mean nightime values (e.g. between 9pm and 7am)? Of course I can filter like this:

```
df <- df %>% 
filter(!hour(times) %in% c(8:20))
```

And then give id to each observation during the night

```
df$ID <- rep(LETTERS[1:round(nrow(df)/11)], 
times = 1, each = 11)
```

And finally group and summarise

```
df_grouped <- df %>% 
group_by(., ID) %>%
summarise(value_mean =mean(values))
```

But this is not a good way I am sure. How to do this better? Especially the part where we give ID to the nighttime values

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table::frollmean` to get the means for a certain window time. In your case you want the means for the last 10 hours, so we set the n argument of the function to 10:

```
> df$means <- data.table::frollmean(df$values, 10)
> df
> head(df, 20)
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   times               values means
   <dttm>               <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01 08:00:00   4.15 NA   
 2 2020-01-01 09:00:00   6.24 NA   
 3 2020-01-01 10:00:00   5.17 NA   
 4 2020-01-01 11:00:00   9.20 NA   
 5 2020-01-01 12:00:00  12.3  NA   
 6 2020-01-01 13:00:00   2.93 NA   
 7 2020-01-01 14:00:00   9.12 NA   
 8 2020-01-01 15:00:00   9.72 NA   
 9 2020-01-01 16:00:00  12.0  NA   
10 2020-01-01 17:00:00  13.4   8.41
11 2020-01-01 18:00:00  10.2   9.01
12 2020-01-01 19:00:00   1.97  8.59
13 2020-01-01 20:00:00  11.9   9.26
14 2020-01-01 21:00:00   8.84  9.23
15 2020-01-01 22:00:00  10.1   9.01
16 2020-01-01 23:00:00   3.76  9.09
17 2020-01-02 00:00:00   9.98  9.18
18 2020-01-02 01:00:00   5.56  8.76
19 2020-01-02 02:00:00   5.22  8.09
20 2020-01-02 03:00:00   6.36  7.39
```

Each row in the mean column will be the mean of that same row value column with the 9 last rows of the value column. Of course there will be some NAs.

Maybe you should give some look to the tsibble package, built to manipulate time series.

You can parametrize the difference between the times you want, but they need to be evenly spaced in your data to use this solution:

```
n <- diff(which(grepl('20:00:00|08:00:00', df$times))) + 1
n <- unique(n)
df$means <- data.table::frollmean(df$values, n)

> head(df, 20)
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   times               values means
   <dttm>               <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01 08:00:00  11.4  NA   
 2 2020-01-01 09:00:00   7.03 NA   
 3 2020-01-01 10:00:00   7.15 NA   
 4 2020-01-01 11:00:00   6.91 NA   
 5 2020-01-01 12:00:00   8.18 NA   
 6 2020-01-01 13:00:00   4.70 NA   
 7 2020-01-01 14:00:00  13.8  NA   
 8 2020-01-01 15:00:00   5.16 NA   
 9 2020-01-01 16:00:00  12.3  NA   
10 2020-01-01 17:00:00   3.81 NA   
11 2020-01-01 18:00:00   3.09 NA   
12 2020-01-01 19:00:00   9.89 NA   
13 2020-01-01 20:00:00   1.24  7.28
14 2020-01-01 21:00:00   8.07  7.02
15 2020-01-01 22:00:00   5.59  6.91
16 2020-01-01 23:00:00   5.77  6.81
17 2020-01-02 00:00:00  10.7   7.10
18 2020-01-02 01:00:00   3.44  6.73
19 2020-01-02 02:00:00  10.3   7.16
20 2020-01-02 03:00:00   4.61  6.45
```

Comment: Thanks. That does the job but contains a lot of extra information but of course, I can filter the useless values. I check whether data.table or tsibble have even better solutions for this.

Comment: Is there a convenient way to do this without hard coding (number 10 inside the brackets)? Could I somehow do the same thing directly using e.g. values 8 PM - 8 AM?

Comment: I don't know if I understood it. Just added a parametrization in the solution, see if it works for you.